# External graphics + axis + additional plots

Tags: pgfplots

my issue is related to the sequence of layers in pgfplots. I have 3 layers:

1. External graphics, which is included by `\addplot graphics`
2. Axis grids and ticks
3. Additional 'quiver' drawing from `\addplot`

which I would like to see in (1-2-3) layer sequence (external graphics is the bottom layer).

I could get (2-1-3) if I do nothing special,

(1-3-2) if I use `axis on top`,

`\pgfplotsset{set layers}` almost do the job, but axis frame is still under the external graphics,

and finally I found (1-2-3) is possible but in case of using two `axis` environments.

So, what is the best way to produce desired (1-2-3) layer sequence?

Here is example of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgfplotsset{set layers}

\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
enlargelimits=false,
axis on top
]

\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1] {demo};

\addplot [thick,yellow,
quiver={u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v},update limits=false},-stealth] 
table
{
    x y u v
    0.4 0.5 0 0.1
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tikz layers? You can declare layers `background, main, foreground` and then place tikzpictures/scopes in each.

Comment: Can you post your code? That'd be helpful. The graphics is not necessary (we can use an example image).

Comment: I've added an example of the file, hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `backgrounds` helps:

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
...
\addplot[on background layer] graphics ...
```

Full example (without `axis on top` and a little more present lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  grid style={semithick, white},
  tick style={semithick, white},
  enlargelimits=false,
]

\addplot[on background layer] graphics [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1] {demo};

\addplot [ultra thick, yellow,
  quiver={u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v},update limits=false},-stealth]
table
{
    x y u v
    0.4 0.5 0 0.1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Thus the image is in the background, the axis stuff with grid follows, on top is the "quiver" drawing.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also the same result I got recently with: `\begin{axis}[set layers,...]` and then `\addplot[on layer=axis background] graphics{...};`, i.e. through the pgfplots features.